# Set orientation issue at UIViewController with iOS8

Tags: objective-c, unity-game-engine, uiviewcontroller, ios8, orientation

I have a problem with setting orientation of UIViewController.

I made a script for invoking message UI in my app worked with unity.

There was no problem until iOS7 but it occurs on iOS8.

The app's initial orientation is landscapeRight and no changes during the app.
But if I invoke the SMS message UI, the UI has portrait orientation. Others(like status bar, and keyboard) are all landscapeRight only the Message UI does.

How can I solve this problem, I've searching this issue by googling but I couldn't find.

Here is my code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMessageComposeViewController.h>
#import "UnityAppController.h"

extern UIViewController *UnityGetGLViewController();

@interface SendSMSViewController : UIViewController
 <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
UIWindow *uiwindow;
}
@end

@implementation SendSMSViewController

-(void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller  
 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{
    switch(result){
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Error occured");
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Sent");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Default");
        break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil];
    [uiwindow release];
}

-(void)sendSMS:(NSString *)text rootwindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    uiwindow = window;

    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller =
    [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){
        controller.body = text;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

@end

extern "C"{
    void _sendSMS(const char* body);
}

void _sendSMS(const char* body){
    NSString *strBody = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: body];

    SendSMSViewController *viewController = nil;
    viewController = [[SendSMSViewController alloc] init];

    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds]];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [viewController sendSMS:strBody rootwindow:window];
}
```

Thanks.